# how to use an outside button to control a Fragment (in Viewpager)?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don't know how to use the button to modify the data in fragment

```
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/bt" >
    <!-- Fragments -->
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a callback. Just code an interface, for example:

```
public interface ExampleCallback {
    void onRequest(int param);
}
```

Then implement it in your fragment:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment implements ExampleCallback {
//...
    @Override
    public void onRequest(int param) {
        //doing an action using params
    }
//...
}
```

In your fragment activity create a field:

```
ExampleFragmentCallback callback;
```

and then in the pager adapter assign a reference to your fragment to it, it can look like that:

```
class ExampleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
//...
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 1){
           ExampleFragment toReturn = new ExampleFragment();
           callback = (ExampleCallback) toReturn;
           return toReturn;
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Of course adapter is an inner class in fragment activity.

On the end implement an onClickListener for the button "bt", and put inside it a call to the function callback.onRequest() with an argument.